# How to build a flywheel crankshaft piston pattern with technic?

Tags: technic, motor

I'm not sure of the name of the pattern, feel free to edit title if you have a better name for the pattern commonly used in engines. I was just wondering if anyone has built this specific pattern in technic lego. The piston part is not important, i only need a flywheel that takes a cranckshaft forwards and backwards repeatedly. Does anyone know some common patterns for this, with a large raduis on the flywheel?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one simple way to accomplish this using just basic parts:

[image: Simple piston]

This isn't quite a pure Technic example, but that construction is almost exactly what was used on the steam cylinders on Emerald Night:

[image: Emerald Night]

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, there are also some specialized parts that make building decorative pistons simple. For example, here's the V8 from the 8880 Super Car:

[image: 8880 V8]

There's also the much earlier piston design on 853:

[image: 853 Pistons]